# No PyGame window appear after I run my project

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pycharm, pyopengl

I install PyGame and OpenGL to my PyCharm for my cube but my problem is the cube never pop up.

Answer (score 0):

We will need some code to be able to help you.

Here is a basic checklist, did you:

1. create the cube from an image?
   1.1. If yes, is the name correct?
   1.2. Is the image in the correct working directory (accessible by the script given its path)?
2. create the cube with pygame.Surface?
   2.1. is the color something different than black?
3. have you called screen.blit(your_cube) to copy the cube image/surface on the screen's surface?
4. have you called pygame.display.flip() to update the whole display accordingly?
5. do you have any screen.fill(color)?
   5.1. if yes, is that placed before blitting anything? Otherwise you would just blit your cube and erase it right after